# How to Detect and Resolve Incorrectly Encoded Varchar Data?

Tags: .net, sql-server, encoding, utf-8

My company has a CRM product that is built on top of a third party webmail system. We use their underlying database, and have extended it with additional databases of our own. As well as using our product, clients are able to log into the webmail system directly.

The webmail databases are SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS encoded and contact names are stored in varchar columns, not nvarchar.

both our product and the webmail product serve pages with Content-Type: text/html charset=utf-8

If a client creates a contact in webmail (the 3rd party system) with the first name "Céline" it ends up stored in the database as "CÃ©line". This is because webmail seems to first convert the data from utf-8 to latin-1 before storing it in the database. The utf-8 char 'é' is stored as two bytes, which in latin-1 are interpreted as the two characters: "Ã©"

However, when the data is retrieved and displayed in webmail, it displays correctly as 'Céline'

The problem is: When reading/writing to contacts from our CRM system, if you set the first name to 'Céline' it is stored as 'Céline', instead of being converted first to latin-1 'CÃ©line'

vice versa, if you create Céline in webmail, it displays in our CRM product as CÃ©line because its not being converted from latin-1 to utf-8

Our product has french internationalization and has been in production for quite a few months, so there is quite a bit of data in the system with both methods of encoding.

i can convert from latin-1 to utf-8 using:

```
var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(Convert.ToString(obj))
string fix2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes).Trim(); //from iso-8859-1 (latin-1) to utf-8
```

But that only works if the data was correctly converted to latin-1 before being stored. So what I really need is a way to determine if the data in the record is a utf-8 encoded string or a latin-1 encoded string.

Or, moving forward, I need a way to mimic what webmail is doing, and make all write operations to the database first convert from utf-8 to latin-1, and all read operations convert from latin-1 to utf-8.

Any ideas? Please let me know if you need additional information/clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some clarifications. There is a difference between converting a byte stream between character encodings (this will modify the bytes) and interpreting a byte stream using different character encodings (this will not modify the bytes, just display them differently). Your webmail application does not convert the `UTF-8` characters on the way to the database, but rather (incorrectly) reinterprets the byte stream.

> Is it possible to detect the incorrectly encoded characters?

In theory, no. The characters, interpreted as `ISO-8859-1` are perfectly valid. In practice you could hand-craft a search for not-so-common characters such as Ã in your example and be able to find the inconsistencies.

> I need a way to mimick what webmail is doing

To reinterpret a string in C# from `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-1` you can use the following line (remember to perform the opposite on the way back from the database)

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(Encoding.UTF8.getBytes("Some text"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I think I understand how if webmail is passing a byte[] that should be interpreted as utf8 to a latin-1 database, that it would display incorrectly in the database, which it is doing. But webmail seems to resolve it on the read side, because when viewing a contact stored as CÃ©line it is displayed in the browser as Céline. So, do you think that the webmail application is incorrectly forgetting to do a conversion before writing to the db, but on the read side it is doing a conversion back to utf8?

Comment: So, since we have control over our webmail database, ideally i would just be able to change the encoding on the database, but then my concern is that webmail would store the data correctly, but as we don't have control over the source code, it would still try to convert back to utf-8, expecting that it is encoded as latin-1 when its actually not.

Comment: Since the webmail application neither do conversion on write nor read the characters will display correctly in the browser, and the application does not care whether it internally misinterprets characters or not. If you are OK limiting yourself with ISO-88590-1, the best option is probably to follow @j3duardogarci4 suggestion to modify the character encoding on the pages served by the webmail application (if possible, this would also require recoding the current database).

Comment: To store UTF-8 in the database, your need to use the NVARCHAR data type, which probably would not help your cause anyhow, as the webmail application believes it is inserting ISO-8859-1, which would proabaly cause a conversion in the database...

Comment: Ok, i've got you, so the webmail application doesn't care about encoding on read or write, the reason the iso-8859-1 stored data is displaying as correct utf-8 data in the browser is because the server is indicating that its utf-8? and vice versa, .Net, in its automagical wisdom, is probably automagically doing the conversion to and from the Database's encoding for us?

Comment: Yes. The browser uses UTF-8 as the HTML pages say so, but the webmail application interprets the bytes as ISO-8859-1 all the way.

Comment: So if I could tell .Net to NOT convert the byte array on the read/write from the database to the database's encoding, but instead just pass the utf-8 byte array in directly, our CRM app would also not care about the encoding in the db, and then when the browser interprets the data as utf-8 it will display correctly?

Comment: In essence, yes. I am just not sure on how to best fool .NET to "avoid the conversion".

Comment: Thanks for your help. At least I understand the problem better now and have some more direction to look for the right solution. Thats the problem with having two apps working side by side, one of which we don't have control over.